# What if a Space Shuttle entered the atmosphere of Venus?

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, venus, carbon

How would a U.S. Space Shuttle's atmospheric entry on Venus differ from reentry on Earth? Say there's a Space Shuttle in a low Venus orbit performing a (re-)entry burn. How would the following atmospheric entry and flight differ from the one on Earth, given the different composition and density of the Venerean atmosphere and the a bit lower gravity, as well as the acid rain? What impact would it have on the shuttle and, if something fails, on the crew?

- I wonder how the atmospheric entry and in-atmosphere flight would be different from that of Earth down to Venus' 1 atm level (which is ~33 miles above the surface)
- and how much lower into Venus' atmosphere a Space Shuttle could get before something fails and *what* would fail (first) and for what reason (extreme pressure/heat/weather?)

Note: a similar question could be asked on Mars but since both planets have an almost entirely carbon dioxide atmosphere the only major difference would be in their gravities. Other than that, down to Venus' 0.006 atm level the entry would be about the same as if a shuttle entered Mars' atmosphere.

Comment: Somewhere at about 5-10km heigh, where the external temperature grows to 100-200C, the electronics stops working. The loss of trajectory control makes the flight controlled only by the aerodynamical forces. Fortunately, there the atmosphere is already enough dense to stabilize it, and at that point, it is already enough slow to remain in a single piece. I think it would arrive in a single piece. As the atmosphere becomes more and more dense, its terminal velocity might be enough slow to even survive the splashdown. Of course at this point, the astronauts in it already faced a painful death.

Comment: The remaining nitrogen tetroxide fuel of the orbital maneuvering engines would likely explode. It will be a glowing wreck.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica  naah, :-)  ,  there would be a "dump all fuel" step in the approach.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Aha, then it will be a glowing wreck with empty OMS fuel tanks. Glow will happen because the 400C surface temperature is enough for things to glow.

Comment: @peterh is right about the cooling but not the stabilization. The orbiter was fly-by-wire; as soon as the cooling and the flight control system failed it would tumble and break up. If the crew wasn't killed by the lack of cooling they would be by the breakup.

Comment: @OrganicMarble fly-by-wire doesn't mean aerodynamic unstable. It just means the controls go through a digital control matrix between input and output. Though given the way the space shuttle looks I have my doubts on the (dynamic) stability. But an airbus is also fly-by-wire, but in case of a complete powerdown it doesn't suddenly tumbles, or stalls.

Comment: Adding this as half-comment half-prompt to read some great science comedy. No answer on flight on Venus is complete without referencing Randall Monroe's "Interplantary Cessna" article at https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/. Highlights include: "The upshot is: Your plane would fly pretty well, except it would be on fire the whole time, and then it would stop flying, and then stop being a plane."

Comment: @OrganicMarble Okay, then it will not break up if it is already enough slow. And it will be enough slow - until $\approx$ 60km it can decelerate as on the Earth. Below 60km, the temperature and the pressure starts to grow, it kills the astronauts and stops the electronic control. But then the shuttle is already slow. This results imho a wreck falling slowly on the Venusian surface, tumbling but in a single piece, roughly like the wreck of a sunken ship "lands" on the seabed. It will arrive vertically. The landing speed will be probably enough slow to remain in a single piece.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Can't speak to the trajectory aspects but the Orbiter crew compartment was very intolerant of crush pressure loading.

> The two negative pressure relief valves protect the crew compartment from being
> crushed if ambient pressure rises above the pressure in the cabin. These negative
> pressure relief valves will crack when ambient pressure is 0.2 psid greater than cabin
> pressure. The negative pressure relief valves are located below the side hatch. Caps
> are provided as a redundant seal to prevent leakage overboard (Figure 2-8). When the
> pressure outside the cabin increases above cabin pressure, the relief valves will crack,
> the caps will pop off, and air will flow into the cabin to equalize the pressure.

[image]

So as soon as the ambient pressure got higher than ~1 bar, the hot unbreathable atmosphere would start flowing into the crew compartment.

Reference: [Shuttle ECLSS training manual](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/383445main_eclss_21002.pdf)

Comment: To be fair, one would expect NASA to modify these valves for a Venus mission, or include enough Terran atmosphere in pressure tanks to equalize upon entry into Venusian atmosphere.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft no one in the real world would ever seriously consider flying an unmodified orbiter into Venus, but the question was what would happen if one did. If one did the required mods, it would no longer be a shuttle orbiter.

Answer (score 12):

In very rough terms, based on data from Wikipedia and NASA sites:

An empty Space Shuttle is around 165 000 pounds (74 843 kg). Height, 56.1 m (184 ft 1 in). Diameter, 8.7 m (28 ft 7 in).  So, a density of about  22.5 $\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$,  while Venus' atmosphere at ground level is 67 $\frac{\text{kg}}{\text{m}^3}$, so the Shuttle would float  somewhere around 15 km altitude.   Or a bit lower if you add a few thousand kg of people and payload.

Comment: Wow, right! But can it withstand some atm of *external* pressure? And, I think only the cabin is sealed, so only its volume counts as hydrostatic buoyant.

Comment: @peterh is correct; the majority of the orbiter volume was vented to ambient.

Comment: Just for comparison: Earth's sea level air density is 1.2 kg/m^3. So Venus' atmosphere is much, much denser.

Comment: Re shuttle payload by not working as a lighter than air blimp https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39523/26356

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica  yeah, we might have to rebuild the hull out of unobtanium, or purchase a General Products hull.

Comment: Reading [Which is the densest gas known?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16439/16035) and seeing [FIG. AII.3. Vapour density of UF6 (calculated at atmospheric pressure) (page 36)](https://www-pub.iaea.org/MTCD/Publications/PDF/te_608_prn.pdf) it looks like even Uranium hexafluoride at its boiling point is only half the density needed to avoid crushing. But it's an interesting thought!

Comment: Radon at its boiling point is no better, but [uranium hexa**chloride**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64269/16035) may be the winner.

Comment: The dimensions are not right. I think they are for the full stack on the launch pad. The orbiter is only 37 meters long, and the diameter is smaller too.

Comment: @Neith thanks for pointing that out.   Any guess as to the diameter?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_orbiter says the cargo bay is 4.6 m wide, but it’s unpressurized anyway. https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/basics/orbit.html says the pressurized volume is 74.3 m3, plus 4.24 m3 for the airlock. If the flight includes a Spacelab or an MPLM, the pressurized volume increases significantly.

Answer (score 2):

### It's going to be a very rough landing.

I'm going to handwave the descent and approach phases, and focus on the landing.

The [Shuttle Landing Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Landing_Facility) is a runway 4600 m long, 91 m wide, and 40 cm thick.  The Space Shuttle needed most to all of the runway for landings, even with drag chutes.

This Venus Shuttle would require a similar prepared runway for landing, if not even longer.  This runway and its foundation would have to be made of materials that can take Venus-standard temperature, pressure, and corrosive atmosphere.  Without that, the craft will be attempting a rough-field landing, and would almost certainly require extensive maintenance and repairs afterwards.

That isn't even the hard part - getting back to space will be difficult!  Making the launch system, stacking the shuttle, and refueling it is left as an exercise for the advanced student.

Comment: Ok, but the density of the atmosphere is half of sea water. The freefall speed of the shuttle is probably not enough for a crash, I think it will arrive softly.

Comment: It's still a rough field landing for a vehicle designed for a very long runway.  So I'm willing to revise my answer to "hard landing needing repairs".

Comment: Even if the electronics would not destroyed by the landing, probably its control constants are not designed for such dense atmosphere. And it is aerodynamically unstable, fly-by-wire, requiring continuous electronical control. If its control can handle this, then it will arrive with head. If not, it will arrive like a thrown dice.

Comment: Note, the 450C temperature probably quickly burns all the 1. painting, 2. gears, and 3., most important: cables. Burned cables cause short circuits.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica: That makes getting back into space even more difficult.